# Clean way to manage an "edit view" for a single item in React/Redux/React-Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I've often come across a situation where I have a list of items in my store (loaded at "boot") and I'm implementing an "edit item view". There are numerous ways to do this but I've yet to find one that really feels solid given a few "constraints".

My edit view "constraints":

1. The selected item must be copied to its own reducer (activeItem). This is
   to a) give me a comparison point so I can tell the user if the item
   has changed or not) and b) in some cases, it allows me to update the
   main item list without affecting the edited item
2. I want the URL to reflect that I'm editing an item and obviously
   directly navigating to the item should work (I typically use React-Router)

If I have an "editItem" action, 1 is easy but fulfilling 2 feels hacky. I need to parse URL params, await that the main list is loaded and then call editItem. A bit of a mess.

If I accept that the URL should be the source of truth for active item, 2 is easy but I'll have to manage a bit more state in my edit component to do 1 (check if an active item is, and if not, dispatch an editItem action.

Is there a good, clean pattern I'm missing?

(Third approach would be to use URL as the source of truth for active item and never "copy" the item over. This means I don't have a comparison point for "has user changed this" though and doesn't allow me to update the "main list" in the background).

Comment: do you mind to share some code?

Comment: Well, basically, the state would have a reducer that maintains a list of items:

`items: [ { "id": 0, "foo": "bar" }, ... ]`

And then if user edits an item, the item is copied to another reducer's slice:
 (cunningly called "activeItem" here):

`activeItem: { id: "0", "foo": "bar" }`

Now discarding is just a question of restoring initial state. The user's edits are trivial to persist using redux-persist etc.  If the URL is the source of truth, then I need to load the item in the route. It's not tough, but it is kinda ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it makes sense to only use the redux store for data which is (or at some point in the future may need to be) accessed from different parts of the app. This helps keeps the structure of the store clean and easy to understand.

Temporary `activeItem` fields etc on the store which will only be looked at by a single display component *over a single component lifecycle* just add bloat, when this data could be nicely tucked away on the state of the only interested component.

Therefore I vote to keep the URL as the source of truth for the active item, and for letting the edit component keep a copy of the original version and perform any "has been changed" checks itself. I would say this is preferable regardless of the added plus of simple direct linking to your URL.

Comment: I don't actually entirely agree with "will just add bloat". I think there are a number of benefits in having the data in the Redux store. Imagine the edit bit is quite complicated (say it's a form with a number of options). If the data is in Redux store, it's trivial to use something like redux-persist to save the current state so the data user has filled in will survive a page refresh.

Comment: @Pasi - good point, if the data needs to persist then there is good reason to keep it on the store. I have modified my answer to try to clarify my point of view.